# Are there $\kappa$-closed $\kappa$-Aronszajn trees for $\kappa>\omega_1$?

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

It is an easy exercise in Kunen that no pruned (i.e. without terminal nodes) $\kappa$-Aronszajn tree is $\kappa$-closed as a partial order (for $\kappa$ regular). I'm wondering if the same is true when we drop the restriction to pruned trees. That is: are there $\kappa$-closed $\kappa$-Aronszajn trees? It is straightforward to show that there aren't when $\kappa= \omega_1$, so my question is really: are there $\kappa$-closed $\kappa$-Aronszajn trees for $\kappa>\omega_1$? I'd also be happy with an answer relative to some extra assumptions like $GCH$.

Comment: Note that this implies that $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$, so without this condition, the answer is immediately no.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks! I actually saw that $2^\omega$ had to be less than $\kappa$, but couldn't figure out how to prove that $\kappa^{<\kappa} = \kappa$. Could you give me a sketch? V. much appreciated!

Comment: Well, there's a theorem of Kurepa that if you have a tree of height $\kappa$ and every level has size $<\lambda<\kappa$, then there is a branch. So in order for the tree to be an Aronszajn tree, the levels must have arbitrarily large size below $\kappa$ cofinally often. I think that you can derive from that the existence of some limit step where you have to realize $2^\lambda$ many branches for every $\lambda<\kappa$. But maybe I'm thinking about trees without maximal nodes, so maybe I'm wrong about that.